# Bootstrap Responsive Embed + Vimeo = Content Security Policy error

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a vimeo video triggering a content security policy error and stopping the rest of my JS from functioning as well.

The relevant html on the page is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 videoPlayer">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/195875285"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the error states:

> Refused to load the script 'data:application/javascript;base64,KGZ1bmN0aW9uKCkgewoJdmFyIG5vb3BmbiA9IGZ1…gpKTsKCQkJfQoJCX0KCX0pKCk7Cgl3aW5kb3cuX2dhcSA9IGdhcS5xZiA9IGdhcTsKfSkoKTs=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://f.vimeocdn.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://js-agent.newrelic.com https://bam.nr-data.net https://f.vimeocdn.com".

I've never encountered this before with the couple of times I've used responsive embed with youtube videos, so I suspect it's a vimeo problem, but none of my searches seem to be providing relevant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I found this error to be caused by the uBlock Origin extension when viewing a site over https in Chrome. It may also be triggered by others like AdBlock.

Try browsing in Incognito or starting your browser without extensions to see if the problem persists.